# How to target select dom element in Jest / RTL with attribute name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to target a select options DOM element for my test, currently the element is as follows:

```
<select name='element'>
   <option value='1'>First element</option>
   <option value='2'>Second element</option>
    <option value='3'>Third element</option>
</select>
```

How would I target this element, as it does not have a class or text to reference it, I did have a look at https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole, but I am a little confused as to which role it would be?

I have tried:

```
const selectElement = await screen.findByRole('select', {name: 'element'});
```

But this does not work? and any idea's on testing the change value would be good?

Comment: Select element has `combobox` as default role.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#technical_summary

Comment: There is also an `option` role to get the `option` elements

Comment: @leo - the `combobox` did not work

Comment: @possum can you elaborate? In the above question context?

Comment: You don't need to add any name if you wanna target the select element.
`screen.getByRole('combobox')` will do.
Otherwise you can try to get an option value like this `screen.getByRole('option', { name: 'First element' } )`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target the `<select>` element you need to use `combobox` as the role:

```
const select = screen.getByRole('combobox');
```

If you want to target a specific option you need to use the `option` role along with a its name:

```
const option2 = screen.getByRole('option', { name: 'Second element'});
```

You can also get all the option by doing `getAllByRole`:

```
const options = screen.getAllByRole('option');
```